# Display: fixed y justify-content: space-between no funcionan juntos

Tags: menu, fixedheader

Estoy intentado hacer un **nav bar al final de un div**, pero el problema es que cuando le digo *position: fixed* a su contenedor padre, el *justify.content: space-between* (que tengo en el contenedor hijo) no funciona.
Éste es el código que tengo:

```
    <main>
            <div>
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="logo col-3">
                    <img src="img/logo.jpg">
                 </div>
        
                 <div class="video-container">
                    <img src="img/Foto1.jpg">
                 </div>
            </div>
    

            <div class="text">
                <p> Some text here </p>
            </div>
    
            <nav>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Ask</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Work in progress</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Idea</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
   
           </div>
        </main>
        <style>
          nav{
            **position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;**
            width: 100%
          }


          nav ul{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            **display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;**
          }

          nav ul li{
            list-style: none;
          }

          nav ul li a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
          }
       <style>
```

Necesito un nav bar con display: fixed, bottom: 0 i justified-content: space-between.
No he encontrado la solución en ningún sitio.

Comment: Pues no se que quieres que te diga, yo he probado el código y el nav me aparece abajo del todo y los items separados con space-between

Comment: pues a mi no mira